# fixed background image size inside popup box for different resolution

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, joomla

I have created one popup box which opens on page load, that pop box contains an image. The pop up box is adjusts size according to the resolution of the image, but the image inside the popup box is not resizing. I am using Joomla plugin for that ([Simple Pop-Up](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/popups-a-iframes/17214)).
   I am trying to change the image accordion to the resolution but it is not reflecting.

This is the code for the pop-up box:

```
<div style="background:url('guntavnuk.pixabytes.co.in/guntavnuk/…; 
<div style=" padding-left: 647px; padding-top: 13px;background:none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;" > 
<iframe src="guntavnuk.pixabytes.co.in/guntavnuk/email.php"; width="300px;" height="190px;" style="overflow:hidden;margin-top:41px;" > </iframe> 
</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: which plugin are you using and can you provide any code that may help?

Comment: Content - Simple Pop-Up is the plugin which i am using for a popup window

Comment: <div style="background:url('http://guntavnuk.pixabytes.co.in/guntavnuk/pop1.png')no-repeat;width:825px;height:515px;margin-left:-9px;"> 
        <div style=" padding-left: 647px; padding-top: 13px;background:none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;" >  
<iframe src="http://guntavnuk.pixabytes.co.in/guntavnuk/email.php" width="300px;" height="190px;" style="overflow:hidden;margin-top:41px;" >   </iframe>
     </div>
   
    </div>                                                                   
this is code inside pop window (popup.php) .this .php file use in article

Comment: and code use in article is: {simplepopup url="http://guntavnuk.pixabytes.co.in/guntavnuk/popup.php"}{/simplepopup}

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the issue on the website. It seems the image is displaying at it's full resolution and so you won't get bigger than that unless you design the image with bigger dimensions. You could then set the width to 100% and height to auto for the image. However you won't be able to accommodate for all screen resolutions due to them varying so much.